# String to String[]

Tags: c#, arrays

```
efStudent.sponsor = Convert.ToString(student.Sponsor);
```

My problem is that I can't convert the `efStudent.sponsor` which is a string to `student.Sponsor`, because it is a `string[]`.

I need some help to convert it from `string` to `string[]`.

Comment: Why would you do that ?

Comment: ...sounds like homework.  What purpose would this solve?  Are you sure you don't mean string to char[]

Comment: The problem is that is error is: cannot convert string to string[].

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean char[] ?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: A `String[]` is an array, which is by definition more than one `String`. You're wanting to convert a single string to more than one string. Just so you are clear on what you are asking. Hopefully you can see why this is confusing us all.

Comment: I just want to save it as an string[], because that value is of an string[] value, if you understand. But can you tell how to convert to char[]?

Comment: Oooh yea I see... But how to save it as an char[]?

Comment: is student.Sponsor a string[] and efStudent.sponsor a string ? Because if so, you want to convert a string[] to string and not otherwise

Comment: Yeaa of course, you are right.

Comment: Can you give me a example or something, its a bit important right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert a `string` to `string[]`, you can initialize a single-element array:

```
efStudent.sponsor = new string[] { Convert.ToString(student.Sponsor) };
```

Comment: Is that even what he needs? Nobody knows.

Comment: @usr: There are valid scenarios where you need to construct a single-element `string[]` array from a given `string` instance, such as when calling the [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Also, I usually find that the best way to get new users to improve their questions is to provide tentative answers that fall short of their actual requirements, prompting them to refine their questions.

Comment: I have not considered this approach previously. I tend to leave a comment and close immediately as unclear question.